# Testing Localstack AWS with Apache Camel

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-camel, localstack

I'm trying to leverage [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) to do local AWS mock testing.  Specifically, I'd like to download a file from a localstack S3 bucket by using an Apache Camel S3 route.  However, I am running into errors.  Here are the steps I've taken...

I've created a test localstack S3 bucket by entering...

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 mb s3://mytestbucket
```

Then, I uploaded a test file to this bucket...

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 cp docker-compose.yml s3://mytestbucket
```

Both operations completed successfully.  In my Java code, I've created a CDI Producer to produce a com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3 client object...

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXX", "XXXXX");
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);
AmazonS3ClientBuilder clientBuilder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:4572", "us-east-1"))
                .withCredentials(credentialsProvider);

AmazonS3 s3Client = clientBuilder.build();
```

Finally, I created a Camel route designed to download the contents of mytestbucket into a local directory...

```
<route id="s3test">
        <from
            uri="aws-s3://arn:aws:s3:::mytestbucket?amazonS3Client=#s3Client&amp;deleteAfterRead=false&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=25&amp;delay=5000" />
        <log message="S3 consumer fired" loggingLevel="DEBUG" />
        <log message="Sending S3 file to ${in.header.CamelAwsS3Key}..." />
        <to
            uri="file://tmp/camel?fileName=${in.header.CamelAwsS3Key}" />
    </route>
```

However, when my application starts up and attempts to run the route, I get the following Exception:

> Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Failed to
>   create route s3test:
>   Route(s3test)[[From[aws-s3://arn:aws:s3:::mytestbucket?amazo...
>   because of Unable to execute HTTP request: mytestbucket.localhost     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:38)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:499)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:93)
>     at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:97)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException:
>   Failed to create route s3test:
>   Route(s3test)[[From[aws-s3://arn:aws:s3:::mytestbucket?amazo...
>   because of Unable to execute HTTP request: mytestbucket.localhost     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:147)  at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWarmUpRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3949)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3856)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3642)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3494)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3253)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3249)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3272)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3249)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3165)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.camel.cdi.CdiCamelExtension.afterDeploymentValidation(CdiCamelExtension.java:425)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SpecialParamPlusBeanManagerStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:144)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
>     at org.jboss.weld.util.Observers.notify(Observers.java:172)     at
>   org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:285)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:273)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:177)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:171)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:53)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:35)
>     ... 12 more Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to
>   execute HTTP request: mytestbucket.localhost  at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1114)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1064)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4330)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4277)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4271)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:835)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.aws.s3.S3Endpoint.doStart(S3Endpoint.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:75)
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:157)
>     at org.apache.camel.impl.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:145)
>     ... 42 more Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   mytestbucket.localhost    at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)  at
>   java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)  at
>   com.amazonaws.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:27)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.DelegatingDnsResolver.resolve(DelegatingDnsResolver.java:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:111)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
>     at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy246.connect(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1236)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056)
>     ... 57 more

I thought that since my `AmazonS3` client specifically indicates that `http://localhost:4572` is my endpoint then it should not reach out to the actual S3 service.  That seems to be the case, but for some reason it is trying to access `mytestbucket.localhost` as if it were a network host.  Any idea what I could be doing wrong here or why this route/configuration isn't working?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else running into this problem, the answer lies in creating the client like this:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("XXXXX", "YYYYY");
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials);
AmazonS3ClientBuilder clientBuilder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                    .disableChunkedEncoding()
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(S3_ENDPOINT, "us-east-1"))
                    .withCredentials(credentialsProvider);
```

The key is `.withPathStyledAccessEnabled(true)`.  Adding that will generate the endpoint URL properly.

Comment: For future reference, on version 2 of aws sdk this is accomplished by `s3AsyncClientBuilder.serviceConfiguration(builder -> builder.pathStyleAccessEnabled(true))`